# Authenticate issue by Personal Access Token issue when all options of "Selected Scope" mode are selected on VSO

Tags: access-token, restful-authentication, azure-devops

I'm coding an app that needs to access VSO by personal access tokens.

If the token is created with the "All scopes" option selected, I can use the token successfully.

However, if the "Selected scopes" option is selected, I cannot use the token although all checkboxes are checked.
[image]

*Here is my code:*

[image]

*Here is my error:*

[image]

Is this issue a bug of VSO or my code has any problems?

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an answer at website: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5564cb2b-4e46-4a41-b12c-bc50304c777b/authentication-issue-using-personal-access-token-when-all-options-of-selected-scope-are-selected?forum=TFService

> Behind the scenes, the TFS Client OM you're using is hitting our older SOAP endpoints and not the newer REST endpoints. Individual scopes only work with the newer REST endpoints due to the mechanics of how scopes work, but we are working on a solution for the SOAP APIs to have scopes as well, although I don't have a timeline on when that will be completed.
>
> For now, using All Scopes in your PATs is your best bet if you don't want to change your code. However, I'd also recommend taking a look at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet for our client libraries. Are you using Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client? These target our REST endpoints, which use our scoping mechanism, so you won't run into this issue.